# How could I implement a score total at the end ( Times Tables Quiz )

Tags: c

I'm trying to create something to test my brothers time's tables. Here is what I have so far.... I really would like to add at the end
something that totals up the score Like 12 out of 12 correct or what ever
But I have no idea how to do this I have tried Google but If you don't know what your looking for it can be quite tricky to find something.

TlDR: Any suggestions on implementing a Tally of correct answers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void){

int answers_eight[] = {8,16,24,32,40,48,56,64,72,80,88,96}; /*Answers List Not sure i need this */

int answer ;                                   /* Empty Container */



//-----------------------------------------------// /* Question One */

printf ("8x1 = : ");
scanf ("%d",&answer);

if (answer == 8) {
    printf ("Correct\n");
} else {
    printf ("Incorrect\n");
}
//-----------------------------------------------// /* Question Two */

printf ("8x2 = : ");
scanf ("%d",&answer);

if (answer == 16) {
printf ("correct\n");
} else {
printf ("Incorrect\n");
}
//-----------------------------------------------// /* Question Three */

printf ("8x3 = : ");
scanf ("%d",&answer);


if (answer == 24) {
printf ("correct\n");
} else {
printf ("Incorrect\n");
}
//----------------------------------------------// /* Question Four */

 printf ("8x4 = : ");
scanf ("%d",&answer);


if (answer == 32) {
printf ("correct\n");
} else {
printf ("Incorrect\n");
}
//---------------------------------------------// /* Question Five */

 printf ("8x5 = : ");
scanf ("%d",&answer);


if (answer == 40) {
printf ("correct\n");
} else {
printf ("Incorrect\n");
}
//--------------------------------------------// /* Question Six */

 printf ("8x6 = : ");
scanf ("%d",&answer);


if (answer == 48) {
printf ("correct\n");
} else {
printf ("Incorrect\n");
}
//-------------------------------------------// /* Question Seven */

 printf ("8x7 = : ");
scanf ("%d",&answer);


if (answer == 56) {
printf ("correct\n");
} else {
printf ("Incorrect\n");
}
//------------------------------------------// /* Question Eight */

 printf ("8x8 = : ");
scanf ("%d",&answer);


if (answer == 64) {
printf ("correct\n");
} else {
printf ("Incorrect\n");
}
//-----------------------------------------// /* Question Nine */

printf ("8x9 = : ");
scanf ("%d",&answer);


if (answer == 72) {
printf ("correct\n");
} else {
printf ("Incorrect\n");
}
//----------------------------------------// /* Question Ten */

 printf ("8x10 = : ");
scanf ("%d",&answer);


if (answer == 80) {
printf ("correct\n");
} else {
printf ("Incorrect\n");
}
//---------------------------------------// /* Question Eleven */

 printf ("8x11 = : ");
 scanf ("%d",&answer);


if (answer == 88) {
printf ("correct\n");
} else {
printf ("Incorrect\n");
}
//---------------------------------------// /* Question Twelve */

 printf ("8x12 = : ");
scanf ("%d",&answer);


if (answer == 96) {
printf ("correct\n");
} else {
printf ("Incorrect\n");
}
//--------------------------------------//

return 0;
}
```

**FIXED:**

```
int score = 0;
        int *score_pointer = &score;
```

I used a pointer in the end like this ^

```
 printf ("3x1 = : ");
 scanf ("%d",&answer);

    if (answer == 3) {
        printf ("Correct\n");
        *score_pointer = 1;
    } else {
        printf ("Incorrect\n");
    }
```

And Changed it as I moved though the code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply declare an `int score = 0` variable at the beginning of your program, and increment it when an answer is correct. Then print it at the end.

Comment: Thank's mate will try this out :)

Comment: int score = 0;
 int *score_pointer = &score; 

I used a pointer in the end like this ^

 printf ("3x1 = : ");
 scanf ("%d",&answer);

    if (answer == 3) {
        printf ("Correct\n");
        *score_pointer = 1;
    } else {
        printf ("Incorrect\n");
    }

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're just printing these out in a loop? Every time he answers one correctly you an just increment a counter variable . Then print out that value